# How to melt data.frame with multiple groups and empty suffix

Tags: r, tidyr, melt

I have a `data.frame` where multiple columns needs to be melted together based on the suffix of the column. So all columns ending with "from" should be melted into one column, same for columns ending on "to" and all columns without suffix together and here lies my problem as I cannot melt without appending the column names without suffix with "xxx". The question is how do I match an empty suffix with the regex formulation in `names_pattern` or is there a different solution without renaming? I am also interested in `data.table` solutions to this problem.

```
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

data <-
  tibble::tribble(
  ~"abc", ~"abcfrom", ~"abcto", ~"def", ~"deffrom", ~"defto",
  1, "2019-05-16", NA, 0, NA, NA,
  1, "2020-01-01", "2020-10-15", 1, "2014-12-17", "2015-03-05",
  1, NA, NA, 1, "2015-01-01", NA
)

data %>% 
  dplyr::rename("abcxxx" = "abc", "defxxx" = "def") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c("variable", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)(xxx|from|to)"
  )
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
>   variable   xxx from       to        
>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
> 1 abc          1 2019-05-16 NA        
> 2 def          0 NA         NA        
> 3 abc          1 2020-01-01 2020-10-15
> 4 def          1 2014-12-17 2015-03-05
> 5 abc          1 NA         NA        
> 6 def          1 2015-01-01 NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
 rename_at(vars(names(.)[!str_detect(names(.), "(from|to)$")]),
        ~ str_c(., 'xxx')) %>% 
 tidyr::pivot_longer(
 everything(),
 names_to = c("variable", ".value"),
 names_pattern = "(.+)(xxx|from|to)"
)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  variable   xxx from       to        
#  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
#1 abc          1 2019-05-16 <NA>      
#2 def          0 <NA>       <NA>      
#3 abc          1 2020-01-01 2020-10-15
#4 def          1 2014-12-17 2015-03-05
#5 abc          1 <NA>       <NA>      
#6 def          1 2015-01-01 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach.

It does not really melt, but splits into chunks of (three) columns based on identical first three characters of the colname. Then set the colnames of the chunks, en rowbind them together again..

```
library( data.table )
setDT( data )

#assuming the first three characters define the group
data.split <- split.default(data, gsub('(^.{3}).*$', '\\1', names(data)))
# $abc
#    abc    abcfrom      abcto
# 1:   1 2019-05-16       <NA>
# 2:   1 2020-01-01 2020-10-15
# 3:   1       <NA>       <NA>
#   
# $def
#    def    deffrom      defto
# 1:   0       <NA>       <NA>
# 2:   1 2014-12-17 2015-03-05
# 3:   1 2015-01-01       <NA>

#set column names (fixed here, but can also be variable if desired)
data.split <- lapply( data.split, setnames, new = c("xxx", "from", "to") )

#bind together
DT <- rbindlist( data.split, use.names = TRUE, idcol = "variable" )
#    variable xxx       from         to
# 1:      abc   1 2019-05-16       <NA>
# 2:      abc   1 2020-01-01 2020-10-15
# 3:      abc   1       <NA>       <NA>
# 4:      def   0       <NA>       <NA>
# 5:      def   1 2014-12-17 2015-03-05
# 6:      def   1 2015-01-01       <NA>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Sadly I cannot assume that the group has a fixed number of characters. One group could have 3, but another one 5

Comment: but 'from' and 'to' is always the same?

Comment: if so, you can use this line.. `data.split <- split.default(data, gsub('from|to', '', names(data)))`